# jQuery calculation on drop down selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Product Selection, anyone can selection any product rate is in select value, then customer can choose no of year limit to 3 and then no of computer limit to 3.

Now if user select product 1 (Price 9.99) for 1 year and 1 pc then code is workinf fine, but I want to give 20% discount on any other changes like anyone select 2 year and 2 pc then (9.99*2*2) then a flat (assume) 20% discount.

```
<select name="dproduct" id="dproduct" required="required">
        <option value="9.99">Product 1</option>
        <option value="14.99">Product 2</option>
        <option value="19.99">Product 3</option>
        <option value="24.99">Product 4</option>
        <option value="39.99">Product 5</option>
        <option value="59.99">Product 6</option>
        <option value="99.99">Product 7</option>
        <option value="149.99">Product 8</option>
        <option value="199.99">Product 9</option>
      </select>

<select name="noofyear" id="noofyear" required="required">
            <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
          </select>

<select name="noofpc" id="noofpc" required="required">
            <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
          </select>
```

My jQuery Code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#dproduct,#noofpc,#noofyear").blur(function () {

    $('#price').val($('#noofpc').val() * $('#dproduct').val() * $('#noofyear').val());

});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dproduct,#noofpc,#noofyear").change(function() {
        var product    = parseFloat($('#dproduct').val());
        var pc_count   = parseInt($('#noofpc').val());
        var year_count = parseInt($('#noofyear').val());

        var price = product * pc_count * year_count;

        if (pc_count > 1 || year_count > 1) {
            price = price * 0.8;
        }

        $('#price').val(price);
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: working very fine but what value comes like 31.968000000000004 so how to do it like 31.97

Comment: also i want 1st year price like 9.99 * 1 (year) so i want to give disound on additonal year not on whole amount